# Change the position of a SVG polygon element

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-animate

I have an empty SVG element on the DOM.

I also have other SVGs on the DOM and inside each one of those, there's an SVG shape.

I can change the position of SVG elements like circle and rect by so they will move inside the empty SVG element by changing their cx/cy x/y.

I'm using the viewportElement.getScreenCTM() and then the transform method which gives me the point inside the SVG I want to move the element into.

I also want to do it for a polygon element.

I know there's a points attribute, but I can't seem to change all the values to make the polygon move from point x/y to point x2/y2. (I know there are multiple x/y for the shape)

I'm doing it in vanilla JS.

**Updated with HTML:**

I want to move the  element which is INSIDE the #pathSvg into the #targetSvg so it would be nested inside of it as a child of it IN THE PLACE THAT I WOULD MOVE THE  ELEMENT THROUGH THE MOUSE MOVE EVENT.

e.g if I move the  element in the position of x/y IN THE TARGET SVG ELEMENT, I want it to be place there as its child.

Hope it is more clearer now.

```
<div>
  <svg>
      <circle id="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />        
    </svg> 
</div>

<svg height="80" width="100" id="pathSvg">
      <path id="tria" d="M 10,150 L 70,10 L 130,150 z" style="fill:rgb(47, 194, 164)"/>
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
    </svg>

<div class="svg-container">
  <svg height="100%" width="100%" id="targetSvg">
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a transform attribute. It works on all shapes

Comment: I know about the transform attribute - it doesn't work for me in this case. I need to APPEND a shape from 1 svg into another and place it in the new SVG at a certain location so it would be a child of the new SVG

Comment: It's going to be difficult for anyone to help without any code to show exactly what you are trying to achieve in a reproducible way. Check this guide for posting questions on stackoverflow: [mcve]

Comment: I have added the HTML to make it more clear.

Comment: We need a [mcve]. I.e. with all the javascript too.